# R Data.Table Copy First Value For Group

Tags: r, data.table

```
data=data.frame("StudentID"=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3),
"Grade"=c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3),
"Score"=c(7,5,3,4,NA,8,9,7),
"ScoreWANT"=c(7,7,7,4,0,8,8,8))
```

I have 'data' shown above without 'ScoreWANT' which is what I hope to generate. 'ScoreWANT' takes the first 'Score' for each "StudentID', the 'Score' at 'Grade' = 1, and fills it down for the rest of the values for each 'StudentID'. There are no missing values at 'Grade' = 1. Any 'NA' values can be replaced with '0'.

Comment: Do yu need `setDT(data)[, ScoreWANT := first(Score), StudentID]`

Comment: If there are values like `c(NA, 2, 3)` for first group,  would that be 2 for 'ScoreWANT

Comment: Yes in that case that would be a 2. However all StudentID will have a 'Score' for 'Grade' at 'Grade' equals to 1 (it is inclusion criteria)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the first non-NA 'Score' for each 'StudentID'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, ScoreWANT := first(Score[!is.na(Score)]), StudentID]
```

---

Or if we need to replace NA with 0 and then apply `first`

```
setDT(data)[, ScoreWANT := first(replace(Score, is.na(Score), 0)), StudentID]
```

---

If we want to replace only where there are no NA's in the 'Score' to `first`

```
setDT(data)[, ScoreWANT := 0][!is.na(Score), ScoreWANT := first(Score), StudentID]
```

Comment: this is great but the one thing is I want to set NA values to 0 and keep them there if that makes sense. So find 'Score' at 'Grade' equals to 1 and fill that score down for all rows of that StudentID unless there is an NA and then the NA is 0 but the first rule applies.

Comment: @bvowe wouldn't `data$Score[4] <- NA; setDT(data)[, ScoreWANT := first(replace(Score, is.na(Score), 0)), StudentID]` this works for you.  Here, the ScoreWANT for ID2 is 0 because the 4th row is now assigned to NA.  when we replace NA to 0, it will be selected as `first` 'Score'

Comment: thanks so much that leaves a '4' in 'data' where there should be 'NA' like in the example

Comment: @bvowe it is just an example to show that if the value is NA, then we get 0 in place of NA in 'scoreWANT'

Comment: when i try both solutions it leaves a 4 instead of a 0.

Comment: @bvowe it is because in your data, the first 'Score' for that StudentID is 4.  If I change that value to NA i..e `data$Score[4] <- NA;`, it would change.  Isn't that you expected

Comment: i see thank you. the expected would be to copy down score at grade = 1 for all values EXCEPT for NA values and in those cases a '0' should be used like in 'ScoreWANT'

Comment: Thank you for your update and patience with me! @akrun works perfect